# With pure CSS, how do I get a perfect(solid, clear) inner border (not a blurry shadow effect)

Tags: html, css

I have made some searches but all related posts were talking about `box-shadow` solution. It's working but it would make the webpage slow. And it's also a bit blurry.

Is there any way to get a perfect inner border (solid and pixel-level clear)

```css
#a {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

#b {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 2px 0 #f00;
}

#a,
#b {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  traditional border, very clear.
</div>
<div id="b">
  border-shadow, blurry
</div>
```

Comment: you have such a border in ur first example so what is the problem here?

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you just remove the box shadow?

Comment: How do I remove the shadow?

Answer (score 0):

To turn an outer border into an inner border, all you have to do is set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the element, this ensures the border is rendered inside the width/height defined for the element.

```css
#a,
#b {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#b {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  traditional (outer) border, very clear.
</div>
<div id="b">
  inner border, very clear.
</div>
```

Comment: It's still slightly changing the size

Comment: Yes, that's because [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) makes sure the box is the exact height/width you have specified it to be, and renders the border inside it, while not setting it adds the padding to the height of the box and renders the border around it. That's just how it works, I don't really see a problem with that. Just pick either one, go with the outer border and set the height of the box to the height minus the padding = `40px`, or go with the inner border and leave the height set to `50px`, you'll end up with the same result.